# Reference to label C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a project in VS2010 with a navigation window and one page.
When the navigation windows loads some action is being done, I also want to give a label on my page some content.

Name of the label: label2

Name of the public partial class of the page is: Page1

namespace: WpfApplication1

This does not work:

```
label2.content = "my string";
```

I understand that label2 is on my page but how do I reference to that page from the navigation window?

I'm a beginner in C# and WPF, I tried a lot and it's driving me crazy not getting it working.

Comment: You will need to expose a reference to the label from your `Page1` class so that your navigation window can see it and access the label.

Comment: Oke, I think that's the right way, but how do I exopse a reference to the label in code?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using a frame on your navigation window, something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Frame  Name="frame1">
        <Frame.Content>
            <pg:Page1 />
        </Frame.Content>
    </Frame>
</StackPanel>
```

The page [Page1] contains a label, named [label1]. In code behind you can set its content like this:

```
    Page1 page = this.frame1.Content as Page1;
    if (page != null) page.label1.Content = "my string";
```

Answer (score 0):

By default references to controls generated via their name are private, you can manually expose them with a property:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Label Label2 { get { return label2; } }

    //...
}
```

Then you should be able to access it via

```
page2.Label2.Content = "Lorem Ipsum";
```

Comment: This does nog work, it says: Ambiguity between 'WpfApplication1.Page1.Label2' and 'WpfApplication1.Page1.Label2'

Comment: You should watch your capitalization, in your question you wrote `label2`, not `Label2`, the field obviously needs to have a different name.

Comment: well, all right now I have put this in my page:
`public Label Label2 
        { 
            get 
            { return label2; } 
        }`

And this in my nav window:

`Page1.label2.Content = "Lorem Ipsum";`

But now it says: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WpfApplication1.Page1.label2'